# bootstrap3-wysiwyg editor object aways undefined

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, wysihtml5

I use this  rich text: https://github.com/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg

It works fine, but I need get the wysihtml5 editor object for run some commands

The [doc](https://github.com/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg#the-underlying-wysihtml5-object) said I can get wysihtml5 editor object use this code:

```
var wysihtml5Editor = $('#some-textarea').data("wysihtml5").editor;
wysihtml5Editor.composer.commands.exec("bold");
```

But wysihtml5Editor is aways undefined

log the $('#some-textarea').data("wysihtml5") print this:

```
Wysihtml5 {el: n.fn.init[1], toolbar: n.fn.init[1], editor:undefined}
```

How to get the editor object?

Comment: Does your editor actually have the ID of "some-textarea"?

Comment: I'm looking through the issues on the github and you may want to look at tihs issue: https://github.com/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg/issues/131, the commenter mentioned that it is fixed in the source file and not the distrubution file. you can try to switch out the two files and see if that'll help

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer by myself, but anyway thanks Daemedeor and DA.!

in bootstrap3-wysihtml5.js  the createEditor method not return , so

```
this.editor =  this.createEditor(toolbarOpts);
```

this.editor is undefined

I add the return like this

```
  createEditor: function(options) {
    options = options || {};

    // Add the toolbar to a clone of the options object so multiple instances
    // of the WYISYWG don't break because 'toolbar' is already defined
    options = $.extend(true, {}, options);
    options.toolbar = this.toolbar[0];

    return this.initializeEditor(this.el[0], options);
  }
```

everything is ok!

Comment: thanks for this its now working. i have read daemedeor comment as it has an issue with the distributed file. and i tried to copy your code @bigzhu and paste it in the bootstrap3-wysiwyg js that im using. i saw that there is declared create editer but i overwrite it. then now it works Thans

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming across this (and to expand a bit on previous answers), I found it a bit frustrating to navigate the various forks of wysihtml5 editor out there.

It also seems there's a lot of questions floating around that's more or less related to the op'ers issue ("editor returns undefined"-kind of questions).

So for starters, this question seems related to this specific fork:

https://github.com/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg

As to the issue of getting the wysihtml5 editor object using the "wysihtml5" data selector, the documentation states:

> You can access the wysihtml5 editor object like this:

```
var wysihtml5Editor = $('#some-textarea').data("wysihtml5").editor;
wysihtml5Editor.composer.commands.exec("bold");
```

In order for that to work, you need to make sure that the file you're referencing (be it **bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.js** or **bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js**) contains this specific commit:

https://github.com/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg/commit/aee1fee7886b34d01e8f238d64d2e6fd9388608c

As Daemedeor notes: 
https://github.com/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg/issues/131 - that commit isn't merged to the distribution, only the source.

Anyways, changing this:

```
this.initializeEditor(this.el[0], options);
```

to this

```
return this.initializeEditor(this.el[0], options);
```

might help you out (certainly did for me).